# Alter statement fails in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table, which has 15K records with primary key & indexes, while i try to add a column at the end, i get

```
Error Code : 1205
Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction


Alter table <tablename> add <columnname> varchar(50);
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Is this a live database with other activity going on at the same time?  Seems like it's trying to lock the table to do the alter, but can't since some other process is using it.

Comment: The question is unanswerable without any more info on what else is going on. Kill the server and restart it. - that will get rid of the locks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make a new table with the same
   structure.
2. Add the column to the new table.
3. Insert the data from the old table
   into the new table.
4. Rename the old table to old.bak
5. Rename the new table to the old
   table.
6. If all went well, delete the
   old.bak.

Comment: Thanks, is there any other approach?

Comment: Yeah, there is a lot of other stuff you could try first. However, without more information, this should either work, or provide us with more information (eg when step 4 blocks).